# What tools are available for Ruby refactoring?

Tags: ruby, ide, refactoring

Are there any tools which support refactoring Ruby code (Rename method, Rename class, Extract method, Move method, ...)?

The best I know is RadRails 2, but Aptana 3 removed this tool.

[Netbeans doesn't support Ruby on Rails anymore](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubySupport) (it has community support)

[Komodo just promises it](http://community.activestate.com/forum/any-plans-refactoring-la-eclipse)

Is there any such tool available? Do you know any? Rubymine ?

No matter if it is a command line tool, a Standalone GUI tool or integrated with Development Environment.

Please avoid answers like "ruby is so good to refactor" or "tests are your best friend"

Comment: For 'rename' methods/classes how about a simple find/replace across your project? For "extract method" you mean "take the selected text and put it in a new method, and then invoke that method from this location, passing in whatever local variables are used within the method"? What do you mean by "move method"?

Comment: @Phrogz: Refactoring is a very well established technique. It has many standard procedures, 'Move method' is one of the simplest and it consists in moving a method from one class to another class where it fits best.

See Martin Fowler's book (http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201485672)
or http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring

Comment: Similar question, but from 2008: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879/refactoring-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RubyMine/IntelliJ does the best of what I use.

The Aptana product does some refactoring, but I'm not familiar with the latest iterations.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and RubyMine has the best support.

Answer (score 2):

[vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/doc/rails.txt#L547) gives you partial extraction - and vim is pretty fast for copying stuff around too ;-)

Comment: The question is about Ruby not Rails. And views parial extraction is just a very tiny part.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans devs don't support ruby anymore, but there [are people who do](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/ruby_development_in_netbeans_ide).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Vim for refactoring RoR applications using this vim plugin: https://github.com/sandeepravi/refactor-rails.vim